# Akka + scala reverse server error

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

I have the question
This is my server https://github.com/vladimirkozhaev/reverse-str
This is my client https://github.com/vladimirkozhaev/string-reverse-client
When I run the server with sbt run command then run following test

package org.reversestr.client

```
import org.scalatest.concurrent.PatienceConfiguration.Timeout
import org.scalatest.{FunSpecLike, Matchers}
import org.scalatest.concurrent.ScalaFutures
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class RClientIntegrationSpec extends FunSpecLike with Matchers with ScalaFutures {
  val client:RClient = new RClient("127.0.0.1:2552")
  describe("reverse str Scala Client") {
    describe("set method") {
      it("should set a value") {
        whenReady(client.setStr("123"), Timeout(1 second)) {
          r => r shouldBe "321"
        }
      }
    }


  }
}
```

Have this strange error message 
Where I'm wrong?

> [INFO] [09/30/2017 22:34:52.985] [pool-4-thread-9]
>   [akka.remote.Remoting] Starting remoting [ERROR] [09/30/2017
>   22:34:53.466] [LocalSystem-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-13]
>   [NettyTransport(akka://LocalSys tem)] failed to bind to
>   /127.0.0.1:2552, shutting down Netty transport [ERROR] [09/30/2017
>   22:34:53.516] [pool-4-thread-9] [akka.remote.Remoting] Remoting error:
>   [Startup failed] [ akka.remote.RemoteTransportException: Startup
>   failed
>           at akka.remote.Remoting.akka$remote$Remoting$$notifyError(Remoting.scala:146)
>           at akka.remote.Remoting.start(Remoting.scala:212)
>           at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.init(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:212)
>           at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.liftedTree2$1(ActorSystem.scala:796)
>           at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start$lzycompute(ActorSystem.scala:793)
>           at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start(ActorSystem.scala:793)
>           at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.start(ActorSystem.scala:809)
>           at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:244)
>           at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:287)
>           at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:232)
>           at org.reversestr.client.RClient.(RClient.scala:11)
>           at org.reversestr.client.RClientIntegrationSpec.(RClientIntegrationSpec.scala:9)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
>           at org.scalatest.tools.Framework$ScalaTestTask.execute(Framework.scala:646)
>           at sbt.TestRunner.runTest$1(TestFramework.scala:76)
>           at sbt.TestRunner.run(TestFramework.scala:85)
>           at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TestFramework.scala:202)
>           at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TestFramework.scala:202)
>           at sbt.TestFramework$.sbt$TestFramework$$withContextLoader(TestFramework.scala:185)
>           at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(TestFramework.scala:202)
>           at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(TestFramework.scala:202)
>           at sbt.TestFunction.apply(TestFramework.scala:207)
>           at sbt.Tests$$anonfun$9.apply(Tests.scala:216)
>           at sbt.Tests$$anonfun$9.apply(Tests.scala:216)
>           at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:44)
>           at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:44)
>           at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
>           at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
>           at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
>           at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
>           at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
>           at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
>           at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
>           at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
>           at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to:
>   /127.0.0.1:2552
>           at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272)
>           at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:417)
>           at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:413)
>           at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:236)
>           at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:191)
>           at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:236)
>           at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
>           at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
>           at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
>           at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
>           at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
>           at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
>           at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
>           at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
>           at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:90)
>           at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
>           at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:43)
>           at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>           at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>           at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>           at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
>   Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
>           at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
>           at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
>           at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
>           at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
>           at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss$RegisterTask.run(NioServerBoss.java:193)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:391)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:315)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.run(NioServerBoss.java:42)
>           at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
>           at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is already another application running at the specified port: 2552.
The exception clearly shows that: `java.net.BindException: Address already in use:`

The quick solution is to clear the port by killing the application that runs at that port.

To clear the port, execute the following command in your shell (or terminal):

```
 kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:2552)
```

Then, retry running your test.

> **Explanation of the commands:**
>
> - **lsof -t -i:2552** returns the process id of the application that runs on port 2552
> - **kill -9 process_id** kills the application with given process id